# Error when creating a record with linklist using OrientJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, orientdb, orientjs

I'm trying to save an object to a database using the OrientJS framework on a NodeJS server.
This object contains some native parameters as well as an array of RIDs that should point to records of another class. See this:

```
var myObj = {
   name: 'myNewObjectName',
   '@class': 'OuterClass',
   parameter: ['#225:13']
}
```

Inside the OrientDB class, the "parameter"-field is defined as a LINKLIST. However, when I try to create a new record for this object:

```
db.record.create(myObj).then(function(record){
   console.log(record);
});
```

I get the exception:

```
Unhandled rejection OrientDB.RequestError: For input string: "#225" at child.Operation.parseError (C:\Users\...\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\protocol33\operation.js:864:13)
at child.Operation.consume (C:\Users\...\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\protocol33\operation.js:455:35)
at Connection.process (C:\Users\...\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\connection.js:399:17)
at Connection.handleSocketData (C:\Users\...\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\connection.js:290:20)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)
```

So somehow the ID following the Cluster is not passed? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? What else could I do?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the RID object to insert links. Try this.

```
const RID = require('orientjs').RID;
.....
var myObj = {
   name: 'myNewObjectName',
   '@class': 'OuterClass',
   parameter: [new RID('#225:13')]
}
```

Comment: HI wolf4food. Thanks a lot for your answer! I found a workaround and now keep the nested RID that I retrieve from orientDB in a dedicated variable. This way, it doesn't mess up any RID-strings. So I didn't exactly use your approach, but I assume, that the issue you pointed out still was the cause for my problem. Just in case anyone else encounters this kind of problem, your suggestion is probably the solution. Cheers!